# phpMyAdmin says no privilege to create database, despite logged in as root user

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I need to login to mysql using root user and create a database. However, when I login to PhpMyAdmin as root user, it tells me that it has "no privileges", therefore cannot create a database.

I did not expect this to happen when I installed phpMyAdmin. Is there a way to fix this? Please help, thank you!

Version info:

OS: OpenSUSE 12.1

MySQL: mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.25, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 6.2

PhpMyAdmin: 3.4.10.2

Comment: from console-client as root is all ok?

Comment: thank you. I'm using opera browser=, and I am able to create databases using mysql -uroot -p.

Comment: Clear cookies for localhost it'll be ok.

Comment: Clearing cookies worked for me!

Answer (score -4, accepted):

It appears to be a transient issue and fixed itself afterwards. Thanks for everyone's attention.

Comment: Obviously, you tried a lot of stuff and one of them worked, there is no magic in it :|

Answer (score 57):

Login using the system maintenance user and password created when you installed phpMyAdmin.
It can be found in the debian.cnf file at /etc/mysql then you will have total access.

```
sudo nano /etc/mysql/debian.cnf
```

Just look - don't change anything!

```
[mysql_upgrade]
host     = localhost
user     = debian-sys-maint       <----use this user
password = s0meRaND0mChar$s       <----use this password
socket   = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Worked for me.

Comment: This worked like a charm! And saved my day, thanks so much for your solution. #ArrowUp :)

Comment: Awesome dude :)

Comment: It works, but it feels not right. Is this the way to go?

Comment: I have no password entry in that file.  Only host and user

Answer (score 26):

If you are using Chrome. try some other browser. there where previous posts on this issue saying that phpmyadmin didnot provide privileges for root on chrome.

or try this

name: root

password: password

Comment: Chrome here too was the problem.

Comment: This is not a problem of chrome. It's a cache data problem try incognito windows and it works on chrome too.

Comment: It is almost 2020 , and I still got this Chrome issue with latest mysql  and phpmyadmin. Unbelievable my friends!

Comment: Yup incognito mode on chrome solved it for me. Thanks @Evilripper.

Comment: Tank you, @JackDev , trying in incognito worked for me

Answer (score 11):

```
sudo mysql
```

enter your (LINUX) account password

```
grant create on *.* to user@localhost;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: your answer while technically correct, is not the answer to the question, the question per se was the root user of the database and not about running mysql as the root user of the system, to login as the root user of the database you should use "mysql -u root -p" in the command line

Comment: Logging in as `sudo mysql` works if the `root` user on the database is setup with the authentication plugin `auth_socket`.  Basically, if the following SQL command is run: `ALTER user 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH auth_socket;`
After this you can again login using sudo mysql (without needing to specify a password)

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me

open config.inc.php file in phpmyadmin root, set auth type from cookie to config

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = ''; // leave blank if no password
```

Comment: I can confirm this worked! Not sure why it was set to cookie in the first place.

Comment: by default it is $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';

Comment: Where is config.inc.php?

Comment: PHPMyAdmin look config.default.php under ./libraries/. If you want to modify the default values then you have to create the config.inc.php file (if not exists) under PHPMyAdmin root directory i.e. ./config.inc.php

Answer (score 2):

Look at the user and host column of your permission. Where you are coming from localhost or some other IPs do make a difference.

Answer (score 2):

Use these:

- username : root
- password : (nothing)

Then you will get the page you want (more options than the admin page) with privileges.

Comment: Didn't accept a blank password

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me(in Chrome):

Login to phpmyadmin, and follow `"Home" -> "Privileges" -> "Reload the Privileges"`. After this, clear your browser's cache and retry.

Regards,
Pedro Sousa

Comment: I see a messsage saying that I haven't privileges to reload.

Comment: @JCarlos are you logging as root, or another user?

Comment: I logged in using root and the default password (I received a password when created a droplet in DigitalOcean using LAMP configuration).

Comment: @JCarlos could you post here the exact message you are getting?

Comment: @PedroSousa where are "Privileges"? I can't see them

Comment: @Line I no longer see the link in my current version of phpMyAdmin. It used to be on the bottom of the page, but if you are looking for a way to reload privileges, you can use the command line and type "mysqladmin -u root -p reload;" without the quotes.

Answer (score 1):

login in the terminal as a root and execute this command:

mysql_secure_installation

Type n in order to not change root password and hit enter,
then type y to remove anonymous users and hit enter.
Type n if you want to disallow root login remotely and hit enter.
Now type y to remove test tables and databases and hit enter, then type y again and hit enter.

and you are good to go :)

Answer (score 1):

I solved my issue like that. You need the change auth_type 'config' to 'http'. 
My older settings auth_type is 'config' then i changed to 'http' and problem solved.

When you changed that area and enter the phpMyAdmin, browser asks you a user and password. You just enter 'root' and dont fill the password area and press enter.

```
/* Authentication type and info */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'http';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Lang'] = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was on my KSWEB app that I downloaded. I am having no privileges error, but when I opened my config.inc.php and changed

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
```

to

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
```

It worked and I now have privileges to create a database.

Comment: After change, I got a lot of errors and can't see the login form (/phpmyadmin just show error messages).

Answer (score 0):

This is a most common problem after installing phpmyadmin.
you need to go with following steps for setting a new user.

```
sudo nano /etc/mysql/debian.cnf
```

then you get a file window/terminal where mentioned a user and a password. you have to login with this user and after this you need to create a new user and grant the permissions from following commond.you can run these query in phpmyadmin sql section.

1. `CREATE USER 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED  BY 'password';`
2. `GRANT CREATE, ALTER, DROP, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, SELECT, REFERENCES, RELOAD on *.* TO 'username'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;`
3. `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'username'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;`

and you get new user with all permissions.