# PhpMyAdmin Create Database No Privileges issue on Mac

Tags: database, macos, phpmyadmin

I have just installed the PhpMyAdmin on my Mac (Yosomite 10.10.5), Everything looks fine, But when I log in to PhoMyAdmin as root and try to create a new database, It shows No Privileges

Screenshot here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNfSs.png

Thanks in Advance

Comment: This question has been asked many, many times here.  How is this unique?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [phpMyAdmin says no privilege to create database, despite logged in as root user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11427091/phpmyadmin-says-no-privilege-to-create-database-despite-logged-in-as-root-user)

Answer (score 1):

Log in via phpMyAdmin with a MySQL account that has sufficient privileges (like root). If you don't have such account, ask this MySQL server's manager about it.