# No permission to create Database in Phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to send temperature data from my ardunino to an apache webserver for an university project. So i started with setting up a LAMP-Server with php and a mySQL-database. But when i try to create a datebase for my temperature data in phpmyadmin i get an error ("No permission to create database"). I'm logged in with the phpmyadmin-account.

Other solutions i found suggested to log in with the root user, but it seems like there is no such user? When I run `sudo nano /etc/mysql/debian.cnf` as suggested here:

[phpMyAdmin says no privilege to create database, despite logged in as root user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11427091/phpmyadmin-says-no-privilege-to-create-database-despite-logged-in-as-root-user)

there is no such user.

Logging in as root without a password is also not possible, because aof the AllowNoPassword setting in the config.inc.php.
When i try to change something there, i'm not allowed to change permissions with `sudo chmod`, it's always giving me an error: "Operations not permitted"

I'm really a novice in this topic and don't know what else to do. The server is just for demonstration purposes, so secruity should not be an issue.

Can somebody help?

Comment: Is this your MySQL or one setup by your Uni

Comment: It's mine. I set up MySQL by myself but was not asked to create a user.

Answer (score 0):

Make a backup of config.inc.php first in case something here upset something else in your XAMPP

Then try these settings as part of your config.inc.php

```
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = 3306;
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';

    // make it throw a login dialog so you dont have uid/pwd in the config file
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';    

    // set these next 2 to blank
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = '';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';

    // Allow connection without password, until you add a password to root
    // then change to false
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
```

Try to login using

```
username = root
password = [leave this blank]
```

Once in, add a password to the root account, logout and then log back in with the new password for root.

Its also a good idea to create a non Super User account with access to just the new database you are about to create, and use that account instead of the root account in your new website code